# How to get rid of half pixel artifacts?

Tags: opengl, 2d, sprites

I've been having a bit of trouble using OpenGL to make 2D games. I am using a traditional ortho perspective with just some sprites being rendered and moved around.

It all works perfectly but there is a little graphical artifact that I would like to get rid of. As the sprites move, their edges jitter a little bit; I assume this happens as the position of the sprite goes from a half-pixel coordinate to a nicely rounded up coordinate, and then back again, causing the artifact to intermittently show up.

I also had the exact same problem with text rendering (textured quads technique), when it was sitting at half-pixel coordinates, where it would get blurry and ugly, while at strict integer positions it would show immaculate.

I could force my sprites to integer positions before rendering, which would probably fix the artifact, but at the same time ruin the movement smoothness.

So, does anyone know what is the state of the art solution for this problem? How to handle sprite positioning without artifacts?

Comment: keyword to search: Anti-Aliasing

Comment: If you are using alpha blending, look into pre-multiplied alpha blending: [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre).

Comment: So there is no obvious solution I was missing? I need to "fix" the problem myself. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Well, you could make sure you only ever position things on exact pixel boundaries.

Comment: If you don't want to snap sprite positions to pixel coordinates, you could try to implement better than bilinear filter (e.g. bicubic)